# Installing Win7 form OEM disk under VBOX, where is my CD/DVD driver

Tags: drivers, 14.04, windows-7, virtualbox

I bought new Lenovo T540P.  The plan was to run Windows under VirtualBox on the Ubuntu host.

I managed to unintentionally wipe the original Windows 8.1 that came with the computer off the disk.  But that's ok (I thought), I'll just run Ubuntu (14.04). and got VirtualBox up and running.

I bought a Windows7 OEM disk.  (It is apparently impossible and/or illegal to use the preinstalled Windows inside a VM, and I didn't want dual boot).  Created a VM under VirtualBox, loaded in the CD, and tried to run it.  It started to run and then it asks me for the disk with the CD driver.  I have no idea where to find this.  Why does it need the CD driver.  Can't it use the one that is running the CD now?  Or if it does, where do I find this driver?

EDIT:  As you can see below, I've accepted the answer below.
In answer to terdon's questions:

the message is in the Windows installer:

"required CD/DVD device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVDm or USAB flash drive, please insert it now. Note. If the windows installation media is in the drive, you can safely remove it for this step."

It appears shortly after you select your language, time format and keyboard (first questions the windows installer asks you).

Comment: Who asks you exactly? The Windows installer? At what point does it ask for this? What is the exact message?

Comment: I will edit my initial question to provide these details, which may be useful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the VirtualBox Extension Pack, it may solve the problem.

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.10-93012.vbox-extpack

You could also try creating an ISO image of the disk and mounting that image as the CD drive in the settings for that virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks.  Your first suggestion did not help but your second suggestion was what needed to be done.

Comment: Basically copy the OEM CD to an ISO file and configure VBOX to use that as its source media.  Add your ISO under Settings->Storage as a "Controller IDE".  This is not intuitively obvious but it will cause vbox to use this ISO file as the install media.

Comment: There are lots of Google hits on this error message dating from 5 or 6 years ago from early adopters of Windows 7 trying to build it in prerelease.  Evidently it's a bug in Windows.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out, :-)